# Is there any biographical information available about Yoshihisa Tagami creator of Grey?

Tags: mangaka

In the late 1980's early 90's Viz media published Grey by Yoshihisa Tagami as well as another work of his, Horobi. Grey was later made into an anime and according to [this](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=16128&lookup=source) site, he worked on some other manga and anime, but I have not been able to find any detailed information or interviews about the artist in English (or otherwise). I would like to find out if Tagami is still active in the manga universe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's all the information you can find on the internet about Yoshihisa Tagami:

- **Birthday:** 09-12-1958 (DD-MM-YY) <sup>[Source](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=16128)</sup>
- **Hometown:** Komoro, Nagano, Japan <sup>[Source](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=16128)</sup>
- > Born in 1958, Tagami first achieved manga success in the early 1980s with Karuizawa Syndrome for Big Comic Spirits. What followed was an extremely prolific decade, with nearly 20 titles released over a 10-year span. Of these, GREY (1985), Horobi (1987) and Frontier Line (1987) would all eventually be translated and released in the U.S. Beyond manga, Tegami did character designs for Super High Speed Galvion (1984) and promotional artwork for the Famicom game Ikari (1986). While both GREY and Horobi got slick, squarebound books in English from Viz in the late ’80s (the former was even included a foreward by Harlan Ellison), Tagami has long since slipped from the lexicon of modern fans.<sup>[Source](http://www.zimmerit.moe/yoshihisa-tagami-anime-journalism/)</sup>

  This excerpt seems to imply that he has lost his fandom in the recent times and **may** have left the manga/anime industry. His publications and active part as a staff in the production of any anime indicate that he has not been active in the anime/manga industry for atleast 10 years.
- **Appearance:**<sup>[Source](http://www.zimmerit.moe/yoshihisa-tagami-anime-journalism/)</sup>

  [image]

  You can find find two other pictures of him: [First one](http://www.zimmerit.moe/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/grey_press_event.jpg) on [Zimmerit](http://www.zimmerit.moe/yoshihisa-tagami-anime-journalism/), and the [second one](http://users.skynet.be/mangaguide/tagami_yoshihisa01.jpg) on [Skynet](http://users.skynet.be/mangaguide/au1825.html)
- **List of published manga (in alphabetical order):**

  1. [4 Spirits Plus 2](http://myanimelist.net/manga/86600/4_Spirits_Plus_2)
  2. [Black Jack Alive](http://myanimelist.net/manga/16999/Black_Jack_Alive)
  3. [Frontier Line](http://myanimelist.net/manga/6204/Frontier_Line)
  4. [Grey](http://myanimelist.net/manga/2701/Grey)
  5. [Horobi](http://myanimelist.net/manga/13395/Horobi)
  6. [Karuizawa Syndrome](http://myanimelist.net/manga/12580/Karuizawa_Syndrome)
  7. [Kaseki no Kioku](http://myanimelist.net/manga/48481/Kaseki_no_Kioku)
  8. [Under Ground](http://myanimelist.net/manga/32389/Under_Ground)